# Chaining filterByXXX bug?

Tags: php, sql, propel

I have the following code:

```
$somethingArray = array( 3, 4, 5 );

$myObjects = MyObjQuery::create()
  ->filterBySomething( $somethingArray )
  ->filterById( array( 'min' => $minMyObjID ) )
  ->orderByObjTimestamp('DESC')
  ->find();
```

Which according to the Propel documentation, should result in a SQL command that ends up checking if the 'something' is IN the somethingArray array, and that the id is > $minMyObjID. But instead, the id is IN instead of >.

If I do the following instead:

```
$myObjects = MyObjQuery::create()
  ->filterBySomething( $somethingArray )
  ->where( 'id > ' . $minMyObjID )
  ->orderByObjTimestamp('DESC')
  ->find();
```

The resulting SQL is what I would expect. Is this a Propel bug, or am I misunderstanding the documentation when it comes to filterByXXX parameters?

Comment: Interesting. Is `$minMyObjID` an integer? Have you tried with only one `filterById` without the other `filterBySomething`? Are you using propel 1.6 or earlier?

Comment: propel 1.6, $minMyObjID is an integer - I haven't tried the filterById by itself yet.

Comment: filterById itself does not generate the appropriate SQL when using array( 'min' => $someNumber ), generates IN ($someNumber) instead of >  $someNumber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an issue on the Propel bug tracker: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues/327

This is an official bug. No patch at the moment.

A work around is to use second parameter of `filterById`: `comparison`:

```
->filterById($minMyObjID, '>')
```

Which leads to the same work around you find, but in a more *Propel way*.

Comment: @KSchmidt just a quick ping to tell you that issue is now resolved ;)